# Export data to multiple worksheets excel that contain images using PHP

Tags: php, html, excel, codeigniter

I'm facing problems in exporting data to excel using PHP (Codeigniter).

Here are some of my issues I found:

- Multiple worksheets
- Each worksheet can contain image

I've used some PHP libraries, for the multiple worksheet issue it works, but it doesn't work when I try to include html tag to show the image inside the worksheet :

```
<img src='localhost/../../image.jpg' />
```

Is there any library to solve my issues?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is that path to the image correct? If it is, that's probably your problem.  Most web servers will not allow you to go past web root with `../`.  Also, it is missing `http://`

Comment: Thanks Levi for the reply :), I tried to use a simple HTML tag first before calling the image (<b>bla..bla..bla..</b>), but the HTML tag I used never affect to the data exported to the excel, even the simplest HTML tag..

Comment: Don't use HTML to do this... Excel is not a glorified web page. Use whatever methods are available in the library you are using to include images

Comment: @MarkBaker, Yup.., I realize that it's not a properly way to include images using HTML tag, but till now I haven't got any libraries that can do multiple worksheets + include Image. Do you know any libraries I can use to achieve these issues? Thanks :)

Comment: My own library (PHPExcel, at http://www.phpexcel.net/ or https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/ ) does both multiple sheets and images, and can be used to build either .xlsx or .xls files

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thanks for your help, I've been using your great library & it solved my problems. What I need to do now is just give styling for the table. Thanks :)